# How do I include JavaHelp with my Eclipse project?

Tags: java, swing, javahelp

I am writing some applications that require to have a Help Contents system tied to it. I came across [JavaHelp](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/) which seems perfect for what I need.

The issue I am having is that when you download JavaHelp, it comes with its own bin folder which looks like you are suppose to use separately. However, I am pretty sure if I just copy some of the JAR files I should be able to just place them in the hierarchy in my Eclipse and use it in the project.

What JAR(s) would I need to copy so I can use JavaHelp in my application?

**Update**

I got JavaHelp working rather easily. I had issues with the built in Eclipse Help though. But I appreciate both of your answers!

If anyone is interested in knowing how to add JavaHelp to your project (doesn't have to be Eclipse specific), I will be more than happy to provide the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaHelp [README](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/README.html#contentsoftherelease) details the redistributable jar files that are supplied in the download. Select the jar that suits your needs and add it to your Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1):

While JavaHelp is a good api, Eclipse has its own api for help, and (IMO) it's a much better option for SWT based applications. See [this developerworks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-echelp/) on developing help using the Eclipse help system.

If you're actually creating a swing application, and want to package java help with it, you'll need to create the help documents (help topics, helpset file, map file, TOC, index, full-text search db) and then package those files into a jar for distribution with your application. See the [JavaHelp Users Guide](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=javahelp-2_0_05-guide-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) for details.

For running the help viewer from the Eclipse IDE (and from your application at runtime), all you need is the jar file jhall.jar from the JavaHelp distribution.